_reactDom.default.createRoot is not a function
The last line is causing the error:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./stockChart";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);

The error message:

TypeError
_reactDom.default.createRoot is not a function

The full code is available on codesandbox: ReactDOM.createRoot

react-dom's version should be 18 same as react's version.

I updated react version but the chart is still not displayed

You should look at the documentation. Shouldn't it be import ReactDom from 'react-dom/client'?
